# Modify particular symbol after loading a font in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, math-fonts

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}[
FakeBold=2,
%SmallCapsFont=PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.otf,
%BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold.otf,
%ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
Ligatures=TeX,]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[FakeBold=2]
\newfontfamily{\bask}{GFS Baskerville}
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sum}{\raisebox{-3.5pt}{\scalebox{2}{{{\bask Σ}}}}}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Just testing if the sum operator works.
        \begin{align*}
            F(n)
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
            a
                & \geq b\\
            f
                & :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\\
            f\ast g
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to modify the summation symbol to look like [image]
I took this formula from the answer by ɪdɪət strəʊlə in this post: [Old-style/Antique typesetting in LaTeX/TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/old-style-antique-typesetting-in-latex-tex)

Currently, the output looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but the change should be done at begin document, because `unicode-math` redefines there `\sum` and all other math commands.

There's a better approach, though, so `\sum` will respect the options to `amsmath` about limit placement. The symbol will scale according to the current math style and with `\vcenter` you don't have to guess the amount of lowering.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\setmainfont{Old Standard}[FakeBold=2]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[FakeBold=2]

\newfontfamily{\bask}{GFS Baskerville}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\sum@}{}{\DOTSB\baskervillesum}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\sum}{}{\mathop{\sum@}\slimits@}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\baskervillesum}{}{%
  \mathchoice
   {\makebaskervillesum{2}}% displaystyle
   {\makebaskervillesum{1.5}}% textstyle
   {\makebaskervillesum{1}}% scriptstyle
   {\makebaskervillesum{0.7}}% scriptscriptstyle
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makebaskervillesum}{m}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{\bask Σ}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  F(n)    & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
  f\ast g & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
\end{align*}
\begin{center}% for testing the other styles
$\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$

$\scriptstyle\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$

$\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked. thank you very much