# The font of Albert Einstein's general theory of relativity

Tags: fonts

I would like to find the font of Albert Einstein's general theory of relativity and use it in LaTeX.

Do you have an idea which one it could be?

[image]

Comment: I think the closest realization is the so called Old Standard (`\usepackage{OldStandard}`).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9894/82917 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9894/82917

Comment: TeX is too neat - the hand-crafted look will be hard to achive yet is where most of the charm is (hand-tooled font, hand-kerning, slightly wavy-fluctuations in the base-line, ever-so-slightly rotated-from-the vertical letters here and there as if inserted and tapped with the hammer a touch more than the others, two possible castings of the font in the `e`s, `i` with a fractional quantum of leading too much, `n` with too little, ...)