# New environment to change font for some book quotations

Tags: fonts

I am working on a document that requires block quotes from books, some of which are from the American Colonial period. I found an answer close to what I need that suggested the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
```

It's exactly the font I need, but just not globally.

So what I'm trying to do it call the `[veryoldstyle]` part just for quotes from old book that use that type. I was thinking of trying some sort of `\newenvironment` command but I am not getting anywhere. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's the main font you use for your document. `kpfonts` as well, just without the `veroldstyle` option? Or some other font? Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myoldstyle}{%
    \bgroup
    \par
    \fontfamily{jkpkvos}\selectfont\small
}
{%
    \par\egroup
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{myoldstyle}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{myoldstyle}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or as a `quote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myoldstyle}{%
    \begin{quote}
    \fontfamily{jkpkvos}\selectfont\small
}
{%
    \end{quote}
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{myoldstyle}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{myoldstyle}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be made more glamorous using `etoolbox` goodies and make all `quote` environments to use this font. But this job is left out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not going about that the correct way at all. I do have a follow-up question, if I may. The terminal "s" as found at the end of a word, is set in the book as regular "s." In the package I was trying to use this is accomplished by adding "=" after the word, so "as" would be set "as=" How do I set a regular s in your example?

Comment: @TimKozusko: Sorry I didn't follow. Can you illustrate please?

Comment: Here's the original post I was trying to adapt: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9495/latex-font-for-18th-century-english It has an example of the same kind of text. The "s" at the end of a word is set normally.

Comment: @TimKozusko: Same thing works here, use `as=`.

Comment: It does, I don't know how I didn't get that behavior before -  perhaps I hadn't removed another \usepackage that called the original font family. At any rate, it works great. Thanks so much!